# how to split an iterable in constant-size chunks

Tags: python, algorithm, generator, chunking

I am surprised I could not find a "batch" function that would take as input an iterable and return an iterable of iterables.

For example:

```
for i in batch(range(0,10), 1): print i
[0]
[1]
...
[9]
```

or:

```
for i in batch(range(0,10), 3): print i
[0,1,2]
[3,4,5]
[6,7,8]
[9]
```

Now, I wrote what I thought was a pretty simple generator:

```
def batch(iterable, n = 1):
   current_batch = []
   for item in iterable:
       current_batch.append(item)
       if len(current_batch) == n:
           yield current_batch
           current_batch = []
   if current_batch:
       yield current_batch
```

But the above does not give me what I would have expected:

```
for x in   batch(range(0,10),3): print x
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[3]
[3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[6]
[6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[9]
```

So, I have missed something and this probably shows my complete lack of understanding of python generators. Anyone would care to point me in the right direction ?

[Edit: I eventually realized that the above behavior happens only when I run this within ipython rather than python itself]

Comment: Please do not extensively discuss whether this question is a duplicate or not *here*. Those comments have been removed. The right place to discuss this is [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). For users with a relevant gold badge: remember you can also edit the duplicate list as needed.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

This is probably more efficient (faster)

```
def batch(iterable, n=1):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
        yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]

for x in batch(range(0, 10), 3):
    print x
```

---

**Example using list**

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # list of data 

for x in batch(data, 3):
    print(x)

# Output

[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9, 10]
```

It avoids building new lists.

Comment: For the record, this is the fastest solution I found: mine = 4.5s, yours=0.43s, Donkopotamus = 14.8s

Comment: To be honest, I expected the itertools solutions to be faster.  Glad I could help!

Comment: your batch in fact accepts a list (with len()), not iterable (without len())

Comment: This is faster because it isn't a solution to the problem. The grouper recipe by Raymond Hettinger - currently below this - is what you are looking for for a general solution that doesn't require the input object to have a __len__ method.

Comment: It may be not the most general solution. But it is fast, and it does not return `None`. The example above produces 
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9]

Comment: Why you use min()? Without `min()` code is completely correct!

Comment: [Iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) don't have `len()`, [sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) have `len()`

Comment: what i want to make all the batches of same size. E.g if last list is like[9], then I want to add first two-element of first list [9,0,1].  if I do batch =30, I want to apply same logic, it is possible?

Answer (score 92):

The [recipes in the itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) provide two ways to do this depending on how you want to handle a final odd-sized lot (keep it, pad it with a fillvalue, ignore it, or raise an exception):

```
from itertools import islice, zip_longest

def batched(iterable, n):
    "Batch data into lists of length n. The last batch may be shorter."
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        batch = list(islice(it, n))
        if not batch:
            return
        yield batch

def grouper(iterable, n, *, incomplete='fill', fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into non-overlapping fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, fillvalue='x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='strict') --> ABC DEF ValueError
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='ignore') --> ABC DEF
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    if incomplete == 'fill':
        return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    if incomplete == 'strict':
        return zip(*args, strict=True)
    if incomplete == 'ignore':
        return zip(*args)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Expected fill, strict, or ignore')
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I needed since it pads the last element with a set of None. i.e., None is a valid value in the data I actually use with my function so what I need instead is something that does not pad the last entry.

Comment: @mathieu Replace `izip_longest` with `izip`, which will not pad the last entries, but instead cut off entries when some of the elements start running out.

Comment: Should be zip_longest/zip in python 3

Comment: Is this really a good solution when you want chunks with length in the 100, 1000s or more?

Comment: @PeterGerdes Unless the input iterable already has some exploitable structure (i.e. reshaping a numpy array), this solution should be near optimal even for big chunk sizes.  It runs at C-speed calling the iterator to fill-in tuple elements as fast as possible, and it reuses the output tuple whenever possible.

Comment: @GoogieK `for x, y in enumerate(grouper(3, xrange(10))): print(x,y)` does indeed not fill values, it just drops the incomplete segment altogether.

Comment: As a one liner that drops the last element if incomplete: `list(zip(*[iter(iterable)] * n))`. This has to be the neatest bit of python code I've ever seen.

Answer (score 60):

[More-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/) includes two functions that do what you need:

- [`chunked(iterable, n)`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) returns an iterable of lists, each of length `n` (except the last one, which may be shorter);
- [`ichunked(iterable, n)`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.ichunked) is similar, but returns an iterable of *iterables* instead.

Comment: This is indeed the most fitting answer (even though it requires installation of one more package), and there's also `ichunked` that yields iterables.

Comment: As of python 3.12, the standard `itertools` package implements the batched function https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched

Answer (score 37):

As others have noted, the code you have given does exactly what you want.  For another approach using `itertools.islice` you could see an [example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303279-getting-items-in-batches/) of following recipe:

```
from itertools import islice, chain

def batch(iterable, size):
    sourceiter = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        batchiter = islice(sourceiter, size)
        yield chain([batchiter.next()], batchiter)
```

Comment: Can we yield `batchiter` itself instead of a chain of it ?

Comment: @abhilash No ... this code uses the call to `next()` to cause a `StopIteration` once `sourceiter` is exhausted, thus terminating the iterator.  Without the call to `next` it would continue to return empty iterators indefinitely.

Comment: I had to replace `batchiter.next()` with `next(batchiter)` to make the above code work in Python 3.

Comment: pointing out a comment from the linked article: "You should add a warning that a batch has to be entirely consumed before you can proceed to the next one." The output of this should be consumed with something like: `map(list, batch(xrange(10), 3))`. Doing: `list(batch(xrange(10), 3)` will produce unexpected results.

Comment: Does not work on py3. `.next()` must be changed to `next(..)`, and `list(batch(range(0,10),3))` throws `RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration`

Comment: @mathieu: Wrap the `while` loop in `try:`/`except StopIteration: return` to fix the latter issue.

Answer (score 21):

Solution for Python 3.8 if you are working with iterables that don't define a `len` function, and get exhausted:

```
from itertools import islice

def batcher(iterable, batch_size):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while batch := list(islice(iterator, batch_size)):
        yield batch
```

Example usage:

```
def my_gen():
    yield from range(10)
 
for batch in batcher(my_gen(), 3):
    print(batch)

>>> [0, 1, 2]
>>> [3, 4, 5]
>>> [6, 7, 8]
>>> [9]
```

Could of course be implemented without the walrus operator as well.

Comment: In the current version, `batcher` accepts an iterator, not an iterable. It would result in an infinite loop with a list, for example. There should probably be a line `iterator = iter(iterable)` before starting the `while` loop.

Comment: `from itertools import islice` just to be complete. =)

Comment: Can you please, let me know the significance of the walrus operator here? just for elaboration

Answer (score 11):

This is a very short code snippet I know that does not use `len` and works under both Python 2 and 3 (not my creation):

```
def chunks(iterable, size):
    from itertools import chain, islice
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for first in iterator:
        yield list(chain([first], islice(iterator, size - 1)))
```

Answer (score 10):

Weird, seems to work fine for me in Python 2.x

```
>>> def batch(iterable, n = 1):
...    current_batch = []
...    for item in iterable:
...        current_batch.append(item)
...        if len(current_batch) == n:
...            yield current_batch
...            current_batch = []
...    if current_batch:
...        yield current_batch
...
>>> for x in batch(range(0, 10), 3):
...     print x
...
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9]
```

Comment: Great answer because it does not need to import anything and is intuitive to read.

Answer (score 5):

A workable version without new features in python 3.8, adapted from @Atra Azami's answer.

```
import itertools    

def batch_generator(iterable, batch_size=1):
    iterable = iter(iterable)

    while True:
        batch = list(itertools.islice(iterable, batch_size))
        if len(batch) > 0:
            yield batch
        else:
            break

for x in batch_generator(range(0, 10), 3):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9]
```

Answer (score 5):

I like this one,

```
def batch(x, bs):
    return [x[i:i+bs] for i in range(0, len(x), bs)]
```

This returns a list of batches of size `bs`, you can make it a generator by using a generator expression `(i for i in iterable)` of course.

Comment: This answers the duplicate question but not the current one

Answer (score 4):

```
def batch(iterable, n):
    iterable=iter(iterable)
    while True:
        chunk=[]
        for i in range(n):
            try:
                chunk.append(next(iterable))
            except StopIteration:
                yield chunk
                return
        yield chunk

list(batch(range(10), 3))
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

Comment: Best answer so far, works with every data structure

Comment: Easiest and quickest solution

Answer (score 4):

Moving as much into CPython as possible, by leveraging islice and iter(callable) behavior:

```
from itertools import islice

def chunked(generator, size):
    """Read parts of the generator, pause each time after a chunk"""
    # islice returns results until 'size',
    # make_chunk gets repeatedly called by iter(callable).
    gen = iter(generator)
    make_chunk = lambda: list(islice(gen, size))
    return iter(make_chunk, [])
```

Inspired by more-itertools, and shortened to the essence of that code.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use in my project. It handles iterables or lists as efficiently as possible.

```py
def chunker(iterable, size):
    if not hasattr(iterable, "__len__"):
        # generators don't have len, so fall back to slower
        # method that works with generators
        for chunk in chunker_gen(iterable, size):
            yield chunk
        return

    it = iter(iterable)
    for i in range(0, len(iterable), size):
        yield [k for k in islice(it, size)]


def chunker_gen(generator, size):
    iterator = iter(generator)
    for first in iterator:

        def chunk():
            yield first
            for more in islice(iterator, size - 1):
                yield more

        yield [k for k in chunk()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `reduce` function.

Oneliner:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda cumulator,item: cumulator[-1].append(item) or cumulator if len(cumulator[-1]) < batch_size else cumulator + [[item]], input_array, [[]])
```

Or more readable version:

```
from functools import reduce
def batch(input_list, batch_size):
  def reducer(cumulator, item):
    if len(cumulator[-1]) < batch_size:
      cumulator[-1].append(item)
      return cumulator
    else:
      cumulator.append([item])
    return cumulator
  return reduce(reducer, input_list, [[]])
```

Test:

```
>>> batch([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]
>>> batch(a, 8)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
>>> batch([1,2,3,None,4], 3)
[[1, 2, 3], [None, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work for any iterable.

```
from itertools import zip_longest, filterfalse

def batch_iterable(iterable, batch_size=2): 
    args = [iter(iterable)] * batch_size 
    return (tuple(filterfalse(lambda x: x is None, group)) for group in zip_longest(fillvalue=None, *args))
```

It would work like this:

```
>>>list(batch_iterable(range(0,5)), 2)
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4,)]
```

PS: It would not work if iterable has None values.

Answer (score 0):

You can just group iterable items by their batch index.

```
def batch(items: Iterable, batch_size: int) -> Iterable[Iterable]:
    # enumerate items and group them by batch index
    enumerated_item_groups = itertools.groupby(enumerate(items), lambda t: t[0] // batch_size)
    # extract items from enumeration tuples
    item_batches = ((t[1] for t in enumerated_items) for key, enumerated_items in enumerated_item_groups)
    return item_batches
```

It is often the case when you want to collect inner iterables so here is more advanced version.

```
def batch_advanced(items: Iterable, batch_size: int, batches_mapper: Callable[[Iterable], Any] = None) -> Iterable[Iterable]:
    enumerated_item_groups = itertools.groupby(enumerate(items), lambda t: t[0] // batch_size)
    if batches_mapper:
        item_batches = (batches_mapper(t[1] for t in enumerated_items) for key, enumerated_items in enumerated_item_groups)
    else:
        item_batches = ((t[1] for t in enumerated_items) for key, enumerated_items in enumerated_item_groups)
    return item_batches
```

Examples:

```
print(list(batch_advanced([1, 9, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2], 4, tuple)))
# [(1, 9, 3, 5), (2, 4, 2)]
print(list(batch_advanced([1, 9, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2], 4, list)))
# [[1, 9, 3, 5], [2, 4, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Related functionality you may need:

```
def batch(size, i):
    """ Get the i'th batch of the given size """
    return slice(size* i, size* i + size)
```

Usage:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10][batch(3, 1)]
>>> [4, 5, 6]
```

It gets the i'th batch from the sequence and it can work with other data structures as well, like pandas dataframes (`df.iloc[batch(100,0)]`) or numpy array (`array[batch(100,0)]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import *

class SENTINEL: pass

def batch(iterable, n):
    return (tuple(filterfalse(lambda x: x is SENTINEL, group)) for group in zip_longest(fillvalue=SENTINEL, *[iter(iterable)] * n))

print(list(range(10), 3)))
# outputs: [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9,)]
print(list(batch([None]*10, 3)))
# outputs: [(None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None, None, None), (None,)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```py
def batchify(arr, batch_size):
  num_batches = math.ceil(len(arr) / batch_size)
  return [arr[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size] for i in range(num_batches)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep taking (at most) n elements until it runs out.

```
def chop(n, iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while chunk := list(take(n, iterator)):
        yield chunk


def take(n, iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for i in range(n):
        try:
            yield next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has the following features:

> - Can take lists or generators (no len()) as input
> - Does not require imports of other packages
> - No padding added to last batch

```
def batch_generator(items, batch_size):
    itemid=0 # Keeps track of current position in items generator/list
    batch = [] # Empty batch
    for item in items: 
      batch.append(item) # Append items to batch
      if len(batch)==batch_size:
        yield batch
        itemid += batch_size # Increment the position in items
        batch = []
    yield batch # yield last bit
```