# Split a generator into chunks without pre-walking it

Tags: python, generator

(This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8290397/647991) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/647991), but those are pre-walking the generator, which is exactly what I want to avoid)

I would like to split a generator in chunks. The requirements are:

- do not pad the chunks: if the number of remaining elements is less than the chunk size, the last chunk must be smaller.
- do not walk the generator beforehand: computing the elements is expensive, and it must only be done by the consuming function, not by the chunker
- which means, of course: do not accumulate in memory (no lists)

I have tried the following code:

```
def head(iterable, max=10):
    for cnt, el in enumerate(iterable):
        yield el
        if cnt >= max:
            break

def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    i = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        yield head(i, size)

# Sample generator: the real data is much more complex, and expensive to compute
els = xrange(7)

for n, chunk in enumerate(chunks(els, 3)):
    for el in chunk:
        print 'Chunk %3d, value %d' % (n, el)
```

And this somehow works:

```
Chunk   0, value 0
Chunk   0, value 1
Chunk   0, value 2
Chunk   1, value 3
Chunk   1, value 4
Chunk   1, value 5
Chunk   2, value 6
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx.py", line 15, in <module>
    for el in chunk:
  File "xxxx.py", line 2, in head
    for cnt, el in enumerate(iterable):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Buuuut ... it never stops (I have to press `^C`) because of the `while True`. I would like to stop that loop whenever the generator has been consumed, but I do not know how to detect that situation. I have tried raising an Exception:

```
class NoMoreData(Exception):
    pass

def head(iterable, max=10):
    for cnt, el in enumerate(iterable):
        yield el
        if cnt >= max:
            break
    if cnt == 0 : raise NoMoreData()

def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    i = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        try:
            yield head(i, size)
        except NoMoreData:
            break

# Sample generator: the real data is much more complex, and expensive to compute    
els = xrange(7)

for n, chunk in enumerate(chunks(els, 2)):
    for el in chunk:
        print 'Chunk %3d, value %d' % (n, el)
```

But then the exception is only raised in the context of the consumer, which is not what I want (I want to keep the consumer code clean)

```
Chunk   0, value 0
Chunk   0, value 1
Chunk   0, value 2
Chunk   1, value 3
Chunk   1, value 4
Chunk   1, value 5
Chunk   2, value 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx.py", line 22, in <module>
    for el in chunk:
  File "xxxx.py", line 9, in head
    if cnt == 0 : raise NoMoreData
__main__.NoMoreData()
```

How can I detect that the generator is exhausted in the `chunks` function, without walking it?

Comment: Don't know how to fix it, but that `except` will only catch the exception if it is raised when _creating_ `head`, not when iterating it.

Comment: @tobias_k: sure, I understand that. I am looking for a fix for that ...

Comment: Would it be okay to peek at the first element? You could try to `next` the first element, then raise an exception or return the actual chunk iterator.

Comment: @tobias_k: that would be a good compromise, but not sure how to implement that without losing that element ...

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "pre-walking the generator"?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

One way would be to peek at the first element, if any, and then create and return the actual generator.

```
def head(iterable, max=10):
    first = next(iterable)      # raise exception when depleted
    def head_inner():
        yield first             # yield the extracted first element
        for cnt, el in enumerate(iterable):
            yield el
            if cnt + 1 >= max:  # cnt + 1 to include first
                break
    return head_inner()
```

Just use this in your `chunk` generator and catch the `StopIteration` exception like you did with your custom exception.

---

**Update:** Here's another version, using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to replace most of the `head` function, and a `for` loop. This simple `for` loop in fact does *exactly the same thing* as that unwieldy `while-try-next-except-break` construct in the original code, so the result is *much* more readable.

```
def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for first in iterator:    # stops when iterator is depleted
        def chunk():          # construct generator for next chunk
            yield first       # yield element from for loop
            for more in islice(iterator, size - 1):
                yield more    # yield more elements from the iterator
        yield chunk()         # in outer generator, yield next chunk
```

And we can get even shorter than that, using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to replace the inner generator:

```
def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for first in iterator:
        yield chain([first], islice(iterator, size - 1))
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! I have the full example: if you want I can edit your answer to include it and have it as reference.

Comment: Using the initial example of `for n, chunk in enumerate(chunks(xrange(0,100), 10)):`, this does not appear to work for me. If I `print(n)` in that for loop, I end up with 100 chunks. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @kadrach That is because you are not consuming the chunks before generating the next one. The code only works if each chunk is consumed before the next one is generated; otherwise, how should chunk n know what it's first element is, without actually advancing the iterator until the end of chunk n-1?

Comment: I think it would be nice to behave like `itertools.groupby`, i.e., not change chunks/groups just because they're not consumed. [Possible implementation](https://tio.run/##nVAxbsMwDNz1Cm6RAhVokKUI4C/kA0EG16ETojZpUArQ9POuJKv2Xi4UeMfjnaZXfAgfPyad515lBIqoUWQIQOMkGqF7tMQeKAzUoTE37NPoyV/BZmr7OaCHQD/YHN7dyUCqMo@i0JTnynMF7RPQk4YIxCt1WcylmJCmnrN/@HIC3uDgVuaLcLgt9uylKF59Wd8ojN/RVqmMbDIezsLoajNmUuJod51weI7E99POmey0RM1Oa2Zt@Y42RfVwrHGX1X0hbEos6ev@rVbF5vkX).

Answer (score 17):

Another way to create groups/chunks and not *prewalk* the generator is using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on a key function that uses an [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) object. Since the `count` object is independent of the *iterable*, the chunks can be easily generated without any knowledge of what the *iterable* holds.

Every iteration of `groupby` calls the `next` method of the `count` object and generates a group/chunk *key* (followed by items in the chunk) by doing an integer division of the current count value by the size of the chunk.

```
from itertools import groupby, count

def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    c = count()
    for _, g in groupby(iterable, lambda _: next(c)//size):
        yield g
```

Each group/chunk `g` *yielded* by the generator function is an iterator. However, since `groupby` uses a shared iterator for all groups, the group iterators cannot be stored in a list or any container, each group iterator should be consumed before the next.

Comment: This works 7 to 8 times slower than itertools.chain method published by tobias_k above

Comment: This method works.  Tobias_k's method does not produce the correct result. Create a generator for integers 0 to 21 with a batch size of ten.  Tobias_k's method as written does not produce three groups.  This method does. I don't car that it's slow I care that it works.

Comment: Improvement: Replace `c = count()` and `next(c)//size` with `c = cycle((False,) * size + (True,) * size)` and `partial(next, c)` (changing import to get `cycle` instead of `count` and adding `from functools import partial`). Avoids per-element division and per-element creation of new `int` objects (at minor expense of a `tuple` of constants of size `2 * size` that `cycle` iterates over), saving a little over 35% on runtime. Using `map(operator.itemgetter(1), ...)` would remove the Python code per-element entirely, but testing on 3.9, the benefit there is less than 5%; not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 16):

#### If you can't prewalk a chunk, you have to build this from parts, Python has nothing that will do it entirely for you

###### For timings, see bottom of answer.

To push the most possible work to the C layer (which is often the fastest solution in CPython), and still guarantee unconsumed chunks are discarded, a modified form of [Moses' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40063403/364696) is the best option (`groupby` does the work of cleaning up elements not consumed by the prior group):

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import cycle, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    c = cycle((False,) * size + (True,) * size)  # Make a cheap iterator that will group in groups of size elements
    # groupby will pass an element to next as its second argument, but because
    # c is an infinite iterator, the second argument will never get used
    return map(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, partial(next, c)))
```

If you never need to leave a group unconsumed, you can get a *little* faster with a modified form of [tobiak_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527424/364696):

```
def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    it = iter(iterable)
    make_islice = partial(islice, it, size - 1)
    for first in it:
        yield chain((first,), make_islice())
```

But the incremental benefit to this is small (see timings) so I'd suggest only using it if you *want* the first unconsumed element from a group to become the first element of the next group; otherwise, stick to the `groupby`-based solution that gives you better guarantees.

All that said, are you *sure* the groups need to be lazy? Because there are *much* better/simpler solutions if each chunk can be produced as a `tuple`, consuming each chunk eagerly, but the input as a whole lazily. The best options by Python versions follow:

#### Best semi-eager solution going forward (requires Python 3.12 or higher, expected to release in October 2023), requiring no hand-rolled code at all, and being fastest in *all* scenarios *if* you can prewalk a *chunk*:

As of Python 3.12, there's a built-in for this, [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched). The arguments are the reverse of the `chunker` recipes below, but it behaves the same way (batching into `tuple`s of length `n`, with the final batch potentially being incomplete):

```
from itertools import batched

for batch in batched('ABCDEFG', 3):
    print(batch)
```

will output:

```
('A', 'B', 'C')
('D', 'E', 'F')
('G',)
```

The timings at the bottom of the answer show that it's by far the best solution if you can rely on 3.12+ and can produce the groups as `tuple`s, rather than lazy iterators (spoiler: it takes 15-30% of the time of otherwise-equivalent lazy solutions, depending on whether the group is fully consumed or not). It's implemented at the C layer and [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cfa517d5a68bae24cbe8d9fe6b8e0d4935e507d2/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L184) takes advantage of performance optimizations not available at the Python layer, which lets it out-perform any solution implemented at the Python layer handily. In particular:

- Unlike `tuple`d `islice`s solutions, it always preallocates a `tuple` of size `n` up-front for each batch and populates it directly (where `tuple`ing `islice`s involves building the `tuple` up an element at a time, costing time on *every* batch; it uses amortized growth, but it can still involve a few reallocations per batch)
- Unlike the `zip_longest` solutions (which, thanks to `zip_longest`'s implementation, does do presized `tuple`s, likely the source of its better performance in most cases):

  1. (Every batch waste) It only has to look up the `.__next__` of the object once per batch, not `n` times per batch (a small cost, given the C layer lookup, but it's paid for *every* batch), and
  2. (One-time waste tied to size of final incomplete batch) It doesn't need to create a sentinel for the `fillvalue`, nor locate it after the fact for the final batch (which requires at least `O(log n)` binary search, and pre-3.10, `O(n)` linear search, plus `O(n)` slicing work, for the final batch); `batched` is counting the elements as it pulls them as a side-effect of tracking the index to insert them into within the `tuple`, so when the iterator is exhausted, it stops immediately, and can directly `realloc` the `tuple` down to match the number of elements it was able to pull (avoiding a new `tuple`, and often avoiding any copying at all).

#### Fastest available solution prior to 3.12 for small-medium `n` and/or large numbers of batches (and for 3.10-3.11, it's not meaningfully slower even in pathological cases):

When the chunk size is typically small, the fastest solution is this one, adapted from [rhettg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791887/364696):

```
from itertools import takewhile, zip_longest

def chunker(n, iterable):
    '''chunker(3, 'ABCDEFG') --> ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'),  ('G',)'''
    fillvalue = object()  # Anonymous sentinel object that can't possibly appear in input
    args = (iter(iterable),) * n
    for x in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue):
        if x[-1] is fillvalue:
            # takewhile optimizes a bit for when n is large and the final
            # group is small; at the cost of a little performance, you can
            # avoid the takewhile import and simplify to:
            # yield tuple(v for v in x if v is not fillvalue)
            yield tuple(takewhile(lambda v: v is not fillvalue, x))
        else:
            yield x
```

If performance is critical, especially when chunk sizes are large and you're doing this a *lot*, and you can rely on 3.10+ (which is when `bisect` added support for a `key` argument), you can improve the above a bit by replacing `O(n)` `takewhile` with `O(log n)` bisection, adding `from bisect import bisect` to the imports, and changing:

```
yield tuple(takewhile(lambda v: v is not fillvalue, x))
```

to:

```
yield x[:bisect(x, False, key=lambda v: v is fillvalue)]  # 3.10+ only!
```

---

#### Older answer (still very fast, thanks to pushing all the work to the C layer, but loses to `zip_longest`-based solution above by a little in all but pathological cases [involving small numbers of huge batch sizes], losing by a roughly factor of 2x in common cases):

By using purely C-level builtins (in CPython), no Python byte code is needed to produce each chunk (unless the underlying generator is implemented in Python) which has a huge performance benefit. It does walk each *chunk* before returning it, but it doesn't do any pre-walking beyond the chunk it's about to return:

```
# Only needed on Py2, to get iterator-based map; Py3's is already iterator-based
from future_builtins import map

from itertools import islice, repeat, starmap, takewhile

# operator.truth is *significantly* faster than bool for the case of
# exactly one positional argument prior to 3.10; in 3.10+, you can
# just use bool (which is trivially faster than truth)
from operator import truth

def chunker(n, iterable):  # n is size of each chunk; last chunk may be smaller
    return takewhile(truth, map(tuple, starmap(islice, repeat((iter(iterable), n)))))
```

Since that's a bit dense, the spread-out version for illustration:

```
def chunker(n, iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        x = tuple(islice(iterable, n))
        if not x:
            return
        yield x
```

Wrapping a call to `chunker` in `enumerate` would let you number the chunks if it's needed.

#### Timings (on CPython 3.12.0, on RHEL8)

###### Solutions that lazily consume the group *and* ensure the alignment of groups is maintained, even if a group is not fully consumed:

```
>>> from itertools import *
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> def chunks_moses(iterable, size=10):
...     c = count()
...     for _, g in groupby(iterable, lambda _: next(c)//size):
...         yield g
...
>>> def chunks_moses_optimized(iterable, size=10):
...    c = cycle((False,) * size + (True,) * size)
...    return map(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, partial(next, c)))
...
>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000
... for grp in chunks_moses(b):
...     next(grp)  # Only consume one element, but rest of group skipped for you
...
1.35 ms ± 31.1 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000
... for grp in chunks_moses_optimized(b):
...     next(grp)  # Only consume one element, but rest of group skipped for you
469 μs ± 5.32 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

So pushing the same basic work to the C layer, and avoiding unnecessary Python level `int` manipulation (creation of successive values, division) cuts the work by roughly a third.

###### Solutions that lazily consume the group, and don't consume unprocessed elements

These are equivalent in behavior to prior solutions only if all groups fully consumed before next group started, so we'll compare them to the prior solutions used in fully consumed mode:

```
# Relies on same imports as above
>>> def chunks_tobias(iterable, size=10):
...     iterator = iter(iterable)
...     for first in iterator:
...         yield chain([first], islice(iterator, size - 1))
... 
>>> def chunks_tobias_optimized(iterable, size=10):
...     it = iter(iterable)
...     make_islice = partial(islice, it, size - 1)
...     for first in it:
...         yield chain((first,), make_islice())
... 
>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000; from collections import deque; consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
... for grp in chunks_moses(b):
...     consume(grp)  # Consume all elements one at a time without storing them
...
1.26 ms ± 4.22 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000; from collections import deque; consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
... for grp in chunks_moses_optimized(b):
...     consume(grp)
...
480 μs ± 11.2 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000; from collections import deque; consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
... for grp in chunks_tobias(b):
...     consume(grp)
...
531 μs ± 15.4 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000; from collections import deque; consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
... for grp in chunks_tobias_optimized(b):
...     consume(grp)
...
461 μs ± 24.3 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

So chunking with `chain` and `islice` is *slightly* faster than an optimized use of `groupby`, at the expense of not properly handling partially consumed groups.

###### Solutions that eagerly complete each complete group before returning it (but still lazily process the iterator as a whole)

If you really can't store more than 1-2 elements in memory at once, these won't work, but *usually* that's not a real problem, so consider these options first:

```
>>> def chunks_rhettg_optimized(iterable, size=10):
...     fillvalue = object()
...     args = (iter(iterable),) * size
...     for x in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue):
...         if x[-1] is fillvalue:
...             yield tuple(takewhile(lambda v: v is not fillvalue, x))
...         else:
...             yield x
...
>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000; from collections import deque; consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
... for grp in chunks_rhettg_optimized(b):
...     consume(grp)
...
195 μs ± 8.43 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000; from collections import deque; consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
... for grp in batched(b, 10):
...     consume(grp)
...
142 μs ± 4.87 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

And just for completeness, timings for those solutions when you only examine a single element of the result:

```
>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000
... for grp in chunks_rhettg_optimized(b):
...     grp[0]
...
116 μs ± 712 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit b = b'\0'*10000
... for grp in batched(b, 10):
...     grp[0]
...
75 μs ± 186 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Summary of timing information:

1. If you can afford the memory/resources to use a solution that eagerly produces a `tuple` for the group, rather than producing a lazy iterator over that group, it's much faster than *any* solution that produces group iterators. Producing `tuple`s taking only ~30-45% of the time when using the entire result, and as little as ~15% of the time if you're only using a subset of each result (when comparing lazy group iterator solutions that only use part of each group, but still skip the unconsumed elements prior to the next group, to `itertools.batched` only examining part of the group).
2. If you must use a lazy group iterator solution, an optimized use of `groupby`+`cycle`+`partial`+`itemgetter`+`map` (which will ensure the last group is consumed before the next group is produced, even if the last group wasn't fully consumed by the user) is *almost* as fast as the optimized use of `chain`+`partial`+`islice`, and guarantees an incompletely consumed group will still be consumed before the next group is produced (it does *not* guarantee the group is consumed if the next group isn't requested, but this is usually what you want). The only time I'd consider the trivially faster version that doesn't guarantee complete group consumption prior to the next group is when that's desired behavior (if you don't fully consume a group, you *want* the next group to begin with the first unconsumed element).

Comment: Another ending, maybe good for large n: `yield x[:bisect(x, False, key=lambda v: v is fillvalue)]`

Comment: Or at the expense of a few extra lines for a generator *function* that breaks early (instead of the generator *expression* that doesn't): `yield tuple(unfill())`

Comment: Btw how did you measure how fast they are? Do you have a benchmark script you could share?

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yeah, `bisect` is an option, but in my experience it rarely help much unless `n` is *huge*, and over-optimizing the terminal case doesn't seem worth it, especially when the test is so cheap, the likely batch sizes smaller, and the terminal case unlikely to dominate. Back when I first wrote this, `bisect` didn't support `key` arguments (that wasn't added until 3.10, which released only a couple months before the 20212 updated version of the answer). Frankly, I can't really justify anything beyond `yield tuple(v for v in x if v is not fillvalue)` unless you know perf depends on it.

Comment: @KellyBundy: I don't remember how I tested back then (I think it was `timeit` with the dataset from [rhettg's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791887/364696)), but I just reconfirmed the timings on 3.11.1 with IPython `timeit` magic: `%%timeit from collections import deque; consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend; tochunk = (0,)*1000` as the setup line, with the test being `consume(chunker(3, tochunk))` (where the `3` is to test small chunk sizes, replacing with `31` for medium chunk sizes, or `334` to test pathological cases with huge chunks where the last chunk is mostly filled, but not quite).

Comment: On 3.11.1: For the pathologically long case, the one-liner at the C layer wins ( ~8 µs vs. the more verbose `zip_longest` at ~21 µs). Your proposed `bisect` optimization of the `zip_longest` still loses to the one-liner, in that case, but by less (takes ~10 µs). For every other scenario, the `zip_longest` solution wins handily (with `bisect` typically saving a titch under ~1 µs over `takewhile`). The `bisect` wins pretty reliably, so I'll edit it in (with a 3.10+-only caveat).

Comment: I posted a few somewhat [faster variations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76282575/1672429) of the `zip_longest` solution.

Comment: **"Best solution going forward"** - Actually it doesn't seem like a solution at all, since it does pre-walk, and avoiding that is the entire reason the question exists.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yes, it does prewalk a specific *chunk*, just like the rest of the solution (I call that out in one of the other solutions, when I mention "It does walk each *chunk* before returning it, but it doesn't do any pre-walking beyond the chunk it's about to return" and they all share the same behavior), it just doesn't prewalk the entire iterator. These are optimal on performance (solutions that don't prewalk have performance issues if they are to handle the incompletely consumed chunk iterator case by consuming what's left), but not for cases where you can't store a chunk in memory.

Comment: Hmm, right, your others don't answer the question, either. I didn't (re)read further than the first one last night and thus didn't notice that and didn't see your caveat. So you *knew* that they do exactly what the question doesn't want?

Comment: @KellyBundy: I went back and added proper lazy group iterator solutions (optimized versions of Moses and tobias_k's solutions; the latter didn't need much optimization, but the former was hurting a lot without it), along with comparative timings on 3.12.0, and information to guide a choice (producing `tuple`s is *much* faster/simpler, so unless you're going to exhaust resources doing so, or it would introduce unacceptable latency, you want to do that).

Answer (score 7):

[more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) has provided [chunked](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) and [ichunked](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.ichunked) that can achieve the goal, it is mentioned on the [Python 3 itertools document page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

[image: chunked and ichunked example]

Answer (score 4):

How about using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools

els = iter(xrange(7))

print list(itertools.islice(els, 2))
print list(itertools.islice(els, 2))
print list(itertools.islice(els, 2))
print list(itertools.islice(els, 2))
```

Which gives:

```
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6]
```

Chunker implementation with some tests:

```
import itertools
from typing import Iterable


def chunker(iterable: Iterable, size: int) -> Iterable[list]:
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        chunk = list(itertools.islice(iterable, size))
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk
    

assert list(chunker(range(10), 3)) == [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
assert list(chunker([], 3)) == []
```

Comment: Thanks, but incomplete. Where is the chunker here?

Comment: I've thought about `islice`, as well, but you'd again need some mechanism to find out when the slice is empty and stop then.

Answer (score 3):

Started to realize the usefulness of this scenario when crafting a solution to DB insertion of 500k+ rows at higher speed.

A generator processes the data from source and "yield"s it line by line; and then another generator groups the output in chunks and "yield "s it chunk by chunk.  The second generator is only aware of the chunk size and nothing more.

Below is a sample to highlight the concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def firstn_gen(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
        yield num
        num += 1

def chunk_gen(some_gen, chunk_size=7):
    res_chunk = []
    for count, item in enumerate(some_gen, 1):
        res_chunk.append(item)
        if count % chunk_size == 0:
            yield res_chunk
            res_chunk[:] = []
    else:
        yield res_chunk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for a_chunk in chunk_gen(firstn_gen(33)):
        print(a_chunk)
```

Tested in Python 2.7.12:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
[28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, but found a simpler solution than those mentioned here:

```
def chunker(iterable, chunk_size):
    els = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        next_el = next(els)
        yield chain([next_el], islice(els, chunk_size - 1))

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunker(range(11), 2)):
    for el in chunk:
        print(i, el)

# Prints the following:
0 0
0 1
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
3 6
3 7
4 8
4 9
5 10
```

Comment: This isn't significantly simpler than the final approach given in [`tobias_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527424/364696). Slightly slower actually, as the manual calls to `next(els)` are slower than letting Python help out by using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from itertools import islice
def chunk(it, n):
    '''
    # returns chunks of n elements each

    >>> list(chunk(range(10), 3))
    [
        [0, 1, 2, ],
        [3, 4, 5, ],
        [6, 7, 8, ],
        [9, ]
    ]

    >>> list(chunk(list(range(10)), 3))
    [
        [0, 1, 2, ],
        [3, 4, 5, ],
        [6, 7, 8, ],
        [9, ]
    ]
    '''
    def _w(g):
        return lambda: tuple(islice(g, n))
    return iter(_w(iter(it)), ())
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Moses Koledoye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3125566/moses-koledoye), I tried to make a solution that uses [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) but doesn't require a divide at each step.

The following function can be used as a key to groupby, and it simply returns a boolean, which flips after a pre-defined number of calls.

```
def chunks(chunksize=3):

    def flag_gen():
        flag = False
        while True:
            for num in range(chunksize):
                yield flag
            flag = not flag

    flag_iter = flag_gen()

    def flag_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return next(flag_iter)

    return flag_func
```

Which can be used like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_long_generator = iter("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

chunked_generator = groupby(my_long_generator, key=chunks(chunksize=5))

for flag, chunk in chunked_generator:
    print("Flag is {f}".format(f=flag), list(chunk))
```

Output:

```
Flag is False ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
Flag is True ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
Flag is False ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
Flag is True ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']
Flag is False ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
Flag is True ['z']
```

I've made a [fiddle demonstrating this code](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/a2912b2c-b1fe-42f0-b13d-f03d16bbf5c9/?i=true).

Answer (score 1):

Three variations of [ShadowRanger's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935239) fastest pre-Python-3.12 solution using `zip_longest` to get chunk tuples and removing the fillvalue from the last chunk. They're the `Stefan_*` ones in this benchmark for an iterable with 10^6 elements and chunk size n=2 to n=1000:

[image: benchmark plot]

Tested on Python 3.10.8. No idea what's up with `Stefan_stopped` from n=7 to n=10, I ran the benchmark multiple times and it's always like that.

#### `Stefan_hold`

This one holds one chunk, and for each *next* chunk, yields the held chunk and then holds the next one instead. At the end, unfill and yield the final held chunk.

```py
def chunker(n, iterable):
    fillvalue = object()
    args = repeat(iter(iterable), n)
    chunks = zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    for chunk in chunks:
        for next_chunk in chunks:
            yield chunk
            chunk = next_chunk
        yield unfill(chunk, fillvalue)
```

#### `Stefan_stopped`

ShadowRanger checks `if x[-1] is fillvalue:` for each chunk `x`. In this solution, I instead use the faster `if stopped:` check of a bool value. To make that work, I chain an "empty" iterator to the input whose sole job is to set `stopped` to `True`:

```py
def chunker(n, iterable):
    stopped = False
    def stop():
        nonlocal stopped
        stopped = True
        return
        yield
    fillvalue = object()
    it = iter(iterable)
    most = repeat(it, n-1)
    last = chain(it, stop())
    for chunk in zip_longest(*most, last, fillvalue=fillvalue):
        if stopped:
            yield unfill(chunk, fillvalue)
        else:
            yield chunk
            del chunk
```

#### `Stefan_compress`

This one eliminates Python interpretation during all but the last chunk. It uses `tee` to get three copies of the chunks iterator from `zip_longest`. The `main` copy contributes all but the last chunk. The `fast` copy is one chunk ahead, its sole job is to avoid the last chunk from `main`. The  `slow` copy is one step behind `fast` and provides the last chunk.

```py
def chunker(n, iterable):
    fillvalue = object()
    args = (iter(iterable),) * n
    chunks = zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    main, fast, slow = tee(chunks, 3)
    next(fast, None)
    return chain(
        compress(main, zip(fast, slow)),
        (unfill(chunk, fillvalue) for chunk in slow)
    )
```

#### `unfill`

The helper my solutions use to remove the fillvalue from the last chunk:

```
def unfill(chunk, fillvalue):
    return chunk[:bisect(chunk, False, key=lambda value: value is fillvalue)]
```

#### The `del` optimization

`ShadowRanger_del` is a minor modification of ShadowRanger's solution, deleting the chunk variable after yielding the chunk, so that `zip_longest` can use its optimization of re-using its result tuple. My `Stefan_stopped` also uses this optimization.

Though that only helps/works if the consumer of our chunks iterator *also* doesn't keep a reference to the tuple, for example if it uses `map(sum, chunker(...))` to compute sums of chunks of numbers.

Here's the same benchmark but without that `del` optimization:

[image: benchmark plot without del optimization]

#### Full code

Solutions, correctness checking, benchmarking, plotting.

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import takewhile, zip_longest, chain, compress, tee, repeat
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from collections import deque
import gc
from random import sample
from bisect import bisect


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Solutions
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def ShadowRanger(n, iterable):
    '''chunker(3, 'ABCDEFG') --> ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'),  ('G',)'''
    fillvalue = object()  # Anonymous sentinel object that can't possibly appear in input
    args = (iter(iterable),) * n
    for x in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue):
        if x[-1] is fillvalue:
            # takewhile optimizes a bit for when n is large and the final
            # group is small; at the cost of a little performance, you can
            # avoid the takewhile import and simplify to:
            # yield tuple(v for v in x if v is not fillvalue)
            yield tuple(takewhile(lambda v: v is not fillvalue, x))
        else:
            yield x


def ShadowRanger_del(n, iterable):
    '''chunker(3, 'ABCDEFG') --> ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'),  ('G',)'''
    fillvalue = object()  # Anonymous sentinel object that can't possibly appear in input
    args = (iter(iterable),) * n
    for x in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue):
        if x[-1] is fillvalue:
            # takewhile optimizes a bit for when n is large and the final
            # group is small; at the cost of a little performance, you can
            # avoid the takewhile import and simplify to:
            # yield tuple(v for v in x if v is not fillvalue)
            yield tuple(takewhile(lambda v: v is not fillvalue, x))
        else:
            yield x
            del x


def unfill(chunk, fillvalue):
    return chunk[:bisect(chunk, False, key=lambda value: value is fillvalue)]


def Stefan_stopped(n, iterable):
    stopped = False
    def stop():
        nonlocal stopped
        stopped = True
        return
        yield
    fillvalue = object()
    it = iter(iterable)
    most = repeat(it, n-1)
    last = chain(it, stop())
    for chunk in zip_longest(*most, last, fillvalue=fillvalue):
        if stopped:
            yield unfill(chunk, fillvalue)
        else:
            yield chunk
            del chunk


def Stefan_compress(n, iterable):
    fillvalue = object()
    args = (iter(iterable),) * n
    chunks = zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    main, fast, slow = tee(chunks, 3)
    next(fast, None)
    return chain(
        compress(main, zip(fast, slow)),
        (unfill(chunk, fillvalue) for chunk in slow)
    )


def Stefan_hold(n, iterable):
    fillvalue = object()
    args = repeat(iter(iterable), n)
    chunks = zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    for chunk in chunks:
        for next_chunk in chunks:
            yield chunk
            chunk = next_chunk
        yield unfill(chunk, fillvalue)


funcs = ShadowRanger, ShadowRanger_del, Stefan_stopped, Stefan_compress, Stefan_hold


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Correctness checks
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def run(f):
    return list(f(n, iter(range(N))))
for n in range(1, 10):
    for N in range(100):
        args = n, range(N)
        expect = run(ShadowRanger)
        for f in funcs:
            result = run(f)
            if result != expect:
                raise Exception(f'{f.__name__} failed for {n=}, {N=}')


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Benchmarking
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

benchmarks = []

# Speed
N = 10 ** 6
for n in *range(2, 11), 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000:
  for _ in range(1):
    times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
    def stats(f):
        ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:10]]
        return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '

    for _ in range(100):
        for f in sample(funcs, len(funcs)):
            gc.collect()
            t = timeit(lambda: deque(f(n, repeat(None, N)), 0), number=1)
            times[f].append(t)

    print(f'\n{n = }')
    for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
        print(stats(f), f.__name__)

    benchmarks.append((n, times))


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Plotting
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

names = [f.__name__ for f in funcs]
stats = [
    (n, [mean(sorted(times[f])[:10]) * 1e3 for f in funcs])
    for n, times in benchmarks
]

colors = {
    'Stefan_stopped': 'blue',
    'Stefan_compress': 'lime',
    'Stefan_hold': 'gold',
    'ShadowRanger': 'red',
    'ShadowRanger_del': 'pink',
}
ns = [n for n, _ in stats]
print('%28s' % 'chunk size', *('%5d' % n for n in ns))
print('-' * 95)
x = range(len(ns))
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    ts = [tss[i] for _, tss in stats]
    ts = [tss[i] / tss[0] * 100 for _, tss in stats]
    color = colors[name]
    if color:
        plt.plot(x, ts, '.-', color=color, label=name)
        print('%29s' % name, *('%5.1f' % t for t in ts))
plt.xticks(x, ns, size=9)
plt.ylim(0, 120)
plt.title('chunker(n, $10^6$ elements)', weight='bold')
plt.xlabel('Chunk size n', weight='bold')
plt.ylabel("Time (for complete iteration) in % relative to ShadowRanger's", weight='bold')
plt.legend(loc='lower center')
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('chunker_plot.png', dpi=200)
```

Comment: Ooh, nice tweaks. I highly doubt the `del chunk` will matter (since these batches aren't fixed size, the caller can't unpack them, so the only way it would help is if they *also* manually replaced/`del`-ed their copy of the `tuple`, with the `del` just slowing things down a tiny bit if they didn't), but it's definitely helpful for microbenchmarks (for everything but `Stefan_hold`, which doesn't benefit)! I love the extreme nonsense involved in `Stefan_stopped`. I'm thinking `Stefan_hold` is the best overall option, given `del chunk` often doesn't help, and it's the best without it.

Comment: Quick question: Any reason why you varied between using `repeat(iter(iterable), n)` and `(iter(iterable),) * n`? I strongly suspect the latter wins (the `*` unpacking will `tuple` it anyway), which might affect the timings. I did add some timings to my own answer, but didn't expand them to include your modified solutions (`itertools.batched` will beat  them all eventually, so I was mostly concerned with timing differences among the solutions that use lazy group iterators vs. `tuple` groups).

Answer (score 0):

You've said you don't wish to store things in memory, so does this mean that you can't build an intermediate list for the current chunk?

Why not traverse the generator and insert a sentinel value between chunks? The consumer (or a suitable wrapper) could ignore the sentinel:

```
class Sentinel(object):
    pass

def chunk(els, size):
    for i, el in enumerate(els):
        yield el
        if i > 0 and i % size == 0:
            yield Sentinel
```

Comment: I do not want to traverse the generator. I want to produce a list of generators which **will** walk the original generator *only when* the consumers decide. This way I can pass the list of chunks around for other parts of my code to consume it, without pre-walking the data (which is expensive to compute in my case)

Comment: @blueFast: I'd assume you'd want an *iterator* of iterators, not a `list` of iterators; a `list` of iterators causes problems (e.g. you may believe, incorrectly, that you can random access the iterators and iterate at an offset, when no non-eager-ish solution will let you do it in anything from left-to-right order).

Answer (score -1):

EDIT other solution with a generator of generators

You should not do a `while True` in your iterator, but simply iterate through it and update the chunk number at each iteration :

```
def chunk(it, maxv):
    n = 0
    for i in it:
        yield n // mavx, i
        n += 1
```

If you want a generator of generators, you can have :

```
def chunk(a, maxv):
    def inner(it, maxv, l):
        l[0] = False
        for i in range(maxv):
            yield next(it)
        l[0] = True
        raise StopIteration
    it = iter(a)
    l = [True]
    while l[0] == True:
        yield inner(it, maxv, l)
    raise StopIteration
```

with a being an iterable.

Tests : on python 2.7 and 3.4:

```
for i in chunk(range(7), 3):
    print 'CHUNK'
    for a in i:
        print a
```

gives :

```
CHUNK
0
1
2
CHUNK
3
4
5
CHUNK
6
```

And on 2.7 :

```
for i in chunk(xrange(7), 3):
    print 'CHUNK'
    for a in i:
        print a
```

gives same result.

But **BEWARE** : `list(chunk(range(7))` blocks on 2.7 and 3.4

Comment: This does not provide me with a series of chunks, but with a single iterator with an indication of the chunk it belongs too. It pre-walks the iterator, which is exactly what I want to avoid.