# python: indexing/pagination of two paired lists

Tags: python

Let's say I have two lists like this that must be represented as pairs:

```
cities = ['San Francisco', 'New York', 'Seattle', 'Portland', ]
states = ['CA', 'NY', 'WA', 'OR']
```

And I have a function like this:

```
def list(page):
    return "{0} -> {1} \n {2} -> {3} \n {4} -> {5} \n {6} -> {7}".format(keys[0], values[0], keys[1], values[1], keys[2], values[2], keys[3], values[3])
```

I want to be able to use an integer (here, `page`) to index these pairs display them three at a time. So let's say I have ten pairs of cities and states, `1` it would display the first three, `2` the second three, etc.

Pseudo-ly, I imagine it would look like this:

```
def list(page):
    for page < 2:
        return first triplet
    for page < 3:
        return second triplet
    # etc.
```

But I think there could be a better way, and I'm wondering what that might look like.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Flask?

Comment: Sorry, I was going to also show what I was doing with this code in Flask, but I forgot to put the Flask code in. I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
def list(page):
    page -= 1
    return "{0} -> {1} \n {2} -> {3} \n {4} -> {5}".format(keys[0 + 3*page], values[0 + 3*page], keys[1 + 3*page], values[1 + 3*page], keys[2 + 3*page], values[2 + 3*page], keys[3 + 3*page], values[3 + 3*page])
```

Not the prettiest code but this will make it so if you call `list(2)` it will print out the 2nd group of three pairs. Calling `list(5)` will print the 5th etc.

Note that this code doesn't have error checking so if you call page 4 but only have 10 states you will get an index error.

Comment: You're right that it's not pretty, but it also masks the built-in function `list()`, which I would caution against doing.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What do you mean by your second statement? EDIT: Ok yea, I see what you mean. I didn't think about it because that was the name that OP used.

Comment: To be fair, that's also what I called my function in my example.

Comment: There's never a bad time to stop masking built-ins. :)

Comment: Also, patterns like "`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`" are a good indication that you should be using a `range` object in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
cities = ['San Francisco', 'New York', 'Seattle', 'Portland', ]
states = ['CA', 'NY', 'WA', 'OR']
```

[A function to split a generator into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527006/split-a-generator-into-chunks-without-pre-walking-it):

```
from itertools import islice

def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for first in iterator:    # stops when iterator is depleted
        def chunk():          # construct generator for next chunk
            yield first       # yield element from for loop
            for more in islice(iterator, size - 1):
                yield more    # yield more elements from the iterator
        yield chunk()         # in outer generator, yield next chunk
```

This gives you a generator that yields chunks of a given size. To put it together:

```
>>> for chunk in chunks(zip(cities, states)):
...     for piece in chunk:
...             print('{}, {}'.format(*piece))
...
San Francisco, CA
New York, NY
Seattle, WA
Portland, OR
```

You can also just turn this into a `list` of chunks as follows:

```
>>> places = [list(chunk) for chunk in chunks(zip(cities, states), 3)]
>>> places[0]
[('San Francisco', 'CA'), ('New York', 'NY'), ('Seattle', 'WA')]
```

And print a given chunk:

```
>>> print(*('{}, {}'.format(*place) for place in places[0]), sep='\n')
San Francisco, CA
New York, NY
Seattle, WA
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `islice` and `zip`.

```
from itertools import islice

def list_(page):
    return islice(zip(cities, states), (page - 1) * 3, page * 3)
```

Note, if you're using a version of Python less than 3 you'll want to use `izip`, found in `itertools`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(a,b,n):
return "".join(map(lambda x,y:"{0} -> {1}\n".format(x,y),a[n*3:(n*3)+3],b[n*3:(n*3)+3]))
```

This shouldn't try to index past the array bounds and would allow you to return a page of 1-2 entries without explicit bounds checking or exception handling. You may want to ensure you have arrays of equal length, otherwise you get some combo of

```
None -> StateN
```