# how to print this pattern using python iterator

Tags: python

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
head = 'head'
tail = 'tail'
```

suppose we can and can only get the iterator of some iterable(L).
and we can not know the length of L.
Is that possible to print the iterable as:

```
'head123tail'
'head456tail' 
'head789tail' 
'head10tail'
```

My try at it is as follows.

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
head = 'head'
tail = 'tail'
slice_size = 3

i = iter(L)
try:
    while True:
        counter = 0
        while counter < slice_size:
            e = next(i)
            if counter == 0:
                print(head, end='')
            print(e, end='')
            counter += 1
        else:
            print(tail)
except StopIteration:
    if counter > 0:
        print(tail)
```

Comment: You'll have to buffer your 'head', and print it only after next has succeeded, since you can't predict what's next in an iterator without consuming it.

Comment: @ Jacques, thanks for your suggestion. I modify my preliminary question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

`groupby` on the key function `lambda _: next(c)//3` groups the items in the iterables in *threes*  in successions. The logic uses the integer division of the next object in the count item on 3:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
head = 'head'
tail = 'tail'

c = count()    
for _, g in groupby(L, lambda _: next(c)//3):
    item = head + ''.join(map(str, g)) + tail
    print(item)
```

*Output*:

```
head123tail
head456tail
head789tail
head10tail
```

Comment: That's a very interesting application of `groupby` and `count`. You might also post this as an answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527006/split-a-generator-into-chunks-without-pre-walking-it) more general question.

Comment: I don't know how to choose between the current two answers. So I `timeit`. I ran them on my slow computer for 1000 times. Koledoye's answer got 2.9803745844324028 seconds; tobias_k's got 8.567057737782685 seconds.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the pointer. Added an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40063403/3125566

Comment: @minion You could at least upvote the answers if you're still not sure of which to accept

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, would you slightly change your answer, since my question is 'we can only get the iterator of some iterable(L).'

Comment: @minion you do `it = iter(L)`, and pass the iterator to groupby. But this would be redundant as an iterator can work directly

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, yes, I know. I just think the answer might be better to completely fit the question. Thanks for your wonderful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can [split the iterator into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527424/1639625) of three, using `chain` and `slice` from `itertools` and a `for` loop, and then join them. The `for` loop will do most of what your `try/while True/except` construct is doing.

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
head = 'head'
tail = 'tail'
slice_size = 3
iterator = iter(L)

from itertools import chain, islice
for first in iterator:
    chunk = chain([first], islice(iterator, slice_size - 1))
    print(head, ''.join(str(x) for x in chunk), tail)
```

However, if your iterator is just a `list`, you can just use `range` with a `step` parameter:

```
for start in range(0, len(L), slice_size):
    chunk = L[start : start + slice_size]
    print(head, ''.join(str(x) for x in chunk), tail)
```