# Python fetchall() with pagination

Tags: python

Can someone help me with the following code? I have more than 130 records, and using `fetchall()` gives me all of them which makes the data impossible to read. Instead I would prefer to fetch 10 records at a time (using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for instance).

This is my code:

```
def getAllPerguntasDB(self):
    query = "SELECT p.id_pergunta,t.tema,d.grau,p.pergunta,p.op1,p.op2,p.op3,p.op4,p.correto FROM perguntas AS p INNER JOIN temas  AS t ON (p.id_tema = t.id_tema) INNER JOIN dificuldade AS d ON (p.id_grau = d.id_grau) ORDER BY t.tema, d.grau ASC;"
    self.cur.execute(query)
    self.result = self.cur.fetchall()
    for row in self.result:
         id_pergunta = row[0]
         tema = row[1]
         grau = row[2]
         pergunta = row[3]
         op1 = row[4]
         op2 = row[5]
         op3 = row[6]
         op4 = row[7]
         correto= row[8]
         print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
         print("id: ", id_pergunta)
         print("Tema:",tema,"\tGrau:",grau)
         print("Pergunta: ", pergunta)
         print("Opção 1: ", op1, "\tOpção 2: ", op2, "\tOpção 3: ", op3, "\tOpção 4: ", op4)
         print("Resposta Correta: ", correto)
         print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: Why not just add `input("press any key")` at the and of `for` loop?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24527006/1639625 Apply this to your `self.results` iterator.

Comment: If i put input("press any key"), i will have to hit enter 130 times, this isn't what i'm looking for. I use pymyql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to count the results using `enumerate` and show an `input` line or similar every 10 lines, using the modulo operator `%`.

```
for i, row in enumerate(self.result, start=1):
    print row
    if i % 10 == 0:
        input("Hit enter to show more")
```

Note: This will show an additional "hit enter" line if you have *exactly* a multiple of 10 of results. To fix this, you can use this slight variation of above approach:

```
for i, row in enumerate(self.result):
    if i > 0 and i % 10 == 0:
        input("Hit enter to show more")
    print row
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used any sort of database querying in Python before, but I'm treating this simply as a problem of generating a sequence of data in fixed-sized chunks, waiting for user input in-between chunks.

The advantage of using *generators* here is that it may allow the program to behave more efficiently if the database results (i.e. the output of `self.cur.fetchall()`) are lazily generated as well; not all database results will be calculated unless the user specifically requests for them (by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> enough times). Note that I can't guarantee this is as I don't know how `fetchall` works.

The batching logic is derived from tobias_k's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527424/1636276). The method to avoid printing the final "Press enter" message was also based on his solution to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717112/1636276).

In the code below, I mock out your database results with a fixed range of values from 0 to 29. However you should be able to adapt the principle of its operation for use with the data you're extracting from the database.

```
from itertools import islice, chain


def get_data():
    # query = "SELECT p.id_pergunta,t.tema,d.grau,p.pergunta,p.op1,p.op2,p.op3,p.op4,p.correto FROM perguntas AS p INNER JOIN temas  AS t ON (p.id_tema = t.id_tema) INNER JOIN dificuldade AS d ON (p.id_grau = d.id_grau) ORDER BY t.tema, d.grau ASC;"
    # self.cur.execute(query)
    # self.result = self.cur.fetchall()

    result = range(0, 30)

    yield from result


def batch(iterable, batch_size):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for first in iterator:
        yield chain([first], islice(iterator, batch_size - 1))


def print_results(batched_results):
    for result in batched_results:
        print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    for i, batched_results in enumerate(batch(get_data(), batch_size=10)):
        if i > 0:
            input('Press enter for more results')
        print_results(batched_results)
```

**Output**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Press enter for more results
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
Press enter for more results
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
```

Comment: @tobias_k No coincidence, I'll add the attribution. I have other details to edit in as well.

Comment: Also, note that his prints one superfluous "press enter" at the end (that's why I did not use it in the end) and you can prevent the `StopIteration` by using `for` loop instead of `while` and `next`

Comment: @tobias_k I've resolved the `StopIteration` error, but I don't believe it's possible for me to rely on for loops or prevent the final "Press enter" if I want to maintain *lazy generation* of the results. Unless you know a way? +1 to your answer by the way; it's succinct.

Comment: Instead of using `try/while/next/except` you can really just use a `for` loop. I also explained this in my original answer. `for res in generator: print_results(res)`

Comment: @tobias_k Ah right yeah, I'm being stupid. Fixed that now. That will still give the final "Press enter" message, which I believe is unavoidable (with lazily generated data) as it won't know that the data sequence has been exhausted until it tries to fetch the next chunk.

Comment: @tobias_k I was wrong about it not being possible for lazily generated data. I saw your solution to the problem below and implemented it that way - it's clever. I've provided attribution. I feel pretty dumb now but on the bright side I'll remember these things for future use.