# What is the best way to generate multiple generators from generator based on length in Python

Tags: python, function, generator

I create a generator and from that I would like to get subgenerators based on a given length.
I have one function but I would like to know if there any more pythonic ways maybe in the itertools module:

```
def create_sub_generators(generator, length=10):
    to_return = []
    for index, element in enumerate(generator):
        if (index % length) == 0 and index > 0:
            yield iter(to_return)
            to_return = []
        to_return.append(element)
    yield iter(to_return)

a = (i for i in range(100))

for index, lengh in enumerate(create_sub_generators(a, 22)):
     print(f'generator num: {index}  lenght: {len([i for i in lengh])}')

generator num: 0  lenght: 22
generator num: 1  lenght: 22
generator num: 2  lenght: 22
generator num: 3  lenght: 22
generator num: 4  lenght: 12
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527006/split-a-generator-into-chunks-without-pre-walking-it

Comment: How can you get those results? Shouldn't the last print line be something like `'generator num: {}  lenght: {}'.format(index, len([i for i in lengh]))`?

Comment: Using python 3.6 f-string

Comment: The difference is that The chuncks will be consumed by different tasks that will run in async

Comment: Oh I see, makes sense.