# iterating over an iterable using generator function

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield, iterable

im facing this question, and I was hoping some of you might help out:

> Write a function that accepts an iterable and a positive number n. The function returns a new iterator that gives values from the original in tuples of length n. Pad missing values with 'None' if needed for the very last tuple.

for example:

`for x in bunch_together(range(10),3): print(x)`

return values are

`(0, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8)
(9, None, None)`

This is what I come up with so far:

```
def bunch_together(iterable,n):
    tup = tuple()
    for item in iterable:
        for i in range(n):
            tup += (i,)
        yield tup
```

but this obviously doesn't work because I didnt accounted for the range at all(the output as of now looks something like this:

```
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)
...#(goes on)
```

I could either create a generator of build an iterator (as in building a class composed of init iter and next)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that [the duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24527006/364696) are actually more complicated than your case (they're trying to avoid filler values). Since you're fine with filler values, [the `grouper` recipe from the `itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) is basically exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing tuple inside `for` loop

```
def bunch_together(iterable,n):

    for k in range(0,len(iterable),n):
        tup = tuple()
        for i in range(k,k+n):
            tup += (iterable[i] if i<len(iterable) else None,) # condition to check overflow
        yield tup

for x in bunch_together(range(10),3): 
    print(x)
```

Output

```
(0, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8)
(9, None, None)
```