# How can I loop a generator in this situation?

Tags: python, django

Here's the question.

I want to use django's `bulk_create` to save more datas at once. But the original result I get from API is a generator with amount data in it. So I want to loop this generator and bulk save data.

My trial was as below：

```
#  a generator with amount data   
l = (
    item for item in range(1,100230, 1)
)

#  base model table
class ModelDemo(models.Model):
    ...


# main logic code

limit = 2000
while l:
    bulk_list = []
    for index, item in enumerate(l):
        bulk_list.append(
            ModelDemo(
                ...
            )
        )
        if index == limit:
            ModelDemo.objects.bulk_create(bulk_list)
            break
```

It's obviously I would lose last `230` data, but I couldn't  find the solution by now.

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the generator? usually just doing list(generator) forces it to compute.

Comment: Have you tried with list comprehension? `bulk_list = [ ModelDemo(...) for i,n in enumerate(range(1,100230, 1))]` then `ModelDemo.objects.bulk_create(bulk_list)`

Comment: @Neil I'm using facebook graph api, and it 's a genarator with over 7w objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain, islice
l = (
    item for item in range(1,10230, 1)
)
limit = 2000

def chunks(iterable, size=10):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for first in iterator:
        yield chain([first], islice(iterator, size - 1))

data = chunks(l, limit)
while data:
    try:
        bulk_list = []
        for index, item in enumerate(next(data)):
            bulk_list.append(
                ModelDemo(
                    ...
                )
            )
        ModelDemo.objects.bulk_create(bulk_list)
    except:
        break
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527424/532312)

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I understand now what your problem is.

All you need to do is make a final bulk_create call after the loop has terminated to handle the final list which was too small.

## main logic code

```
limit = 2000

bulk_list = []
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    bulk_list.append(
        ModelDemo(
            ...
        )
    )
    if index == limit:
        ModelDemo.objects.bulk_create(bulk_list)
        bulk_list.clear() # reset the batch

ModelDemo.objects.bulk_create(bulk_list)
```

I'm not sure what the while loop was there for. And you shouldn't break.