# Iterate over queryset in groups of a certain amount

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Basically, I want to use a Bootstrap Carousel with a queryset. My question is as to how I should iterate over the queryset so that I can put three objects into a div and then the next three into another div and so on depending on the size of the queryset. See the preudocode below.

```
{% for group in object_list/3 %}
 <div class="">
  {% for object in group %}
   <p>{{object}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a filter called chunks like in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527424/8953667):

```py
@register.filter
def chunks(iterable, size):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for first in iterator:
        yield chain([first], islice(iterator, size - 1))
```

and then use the filter in django templates