# Chunking a generator

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

What am I doing wrong here.  Trying to get chunks of a generator using islice, but seems to be running infinitely.

```
from itertools import islice

size = 2

def g():
    for x in range(11):
        print("generating: ", x)
        yield x

while True:
    chunk = islice(g(), size)
    if not chunk:
        break
    print("at chunk")
    for c in chunk:
        print(c)
```

I am getting an output of, that seems to just loop forever and does not seem to increment:

```
at chunk
generating:  0
0
generating:  1
1
at chunk
generating:  0
0
generating:  1
1
at chunk
generating:  0
0
generating:  1
1
at chunk
```

Comment: You create a new generator (starting from 0) each iteration of the while loop...

Comment: All `islice` instances are truthy. You can't tell how many items it will produce without actually iterating over it.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here?  And what you got then?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24527006/1639625

Comment: Compare with the `grouper` recipe in the `itertools` documentation, which uses multiple references to the same underlying iterator to get sequential chunks.

Comment: @tobias_k chepner already pointed that out

Comment: @Tomerikoo I think the question is more about why this particular attempt failed than how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call `g()` you restart the generator from the beginning. You need to assign the result to a variable so it will keep using the same generator.

And as mentioned in a comment, the `islice` object is always truthy. To tell if you reached the end, check whether the `for c in chunk:` loop did anything.

```
from itertools import islice

def g():
    for x in range(11):
        print("generating: ", x)
        yield x

size = 2
gen = g()
while True:
    chunk = islice(gen, size)

    print("at chunk")
    empty = True
    for c in chunk:
        print(c)
        empty = False

    if empty:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't realize I was starting a new generator each time