# Generator does not seem to stop

Tags: python, while-loop, generator, try-except

I have a generator whoms content I need to get into an SQL database. The generator contains more than a million items and while iterating over them I send them in bins of 10.000 into a pandas dataframe, and commit that via the to_sql function into the database.

That works fine as long as I can fill the bin with 10.000 items. However, the StopIteration is never triggered, even though the last item of the generator was called by the next method.

Debugging it, I can see item 1.384.471 is processed in the try-part, and then `while` is still `True`, `next` does not get a new item, but instead of activating the except-part the program simply runs into nirvana.

It would be nice if some of you can point me to my mistake.

```
import ijson
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

def connect_to_database():
    engine = sa.create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{USER}:{PWD}@{SERVERNAME}:{PORT}/{DB}")

    return engine

engine = connect_to_database()

def create_content(objects, table_name):
''' simple helper function to get content
for every object list from the JSON file'''

    item_lst = []
    item_count = 0

    while True:
        try:
            item = next(objects)
        
            value_conversion(item)
            item_lst.append(item)
            if item_count == 1380000 and len(item_lst) == 4470:
                print('Watch it!')
        
            if len(item_lst) == 10000:
                item_count += len(item_lst)
                submit_sql(table_name, item_lst)
                item_lst.clear()

        except StopIteration:
            if len(item_lst) > 0:
                item_count += len(item_lst)
                submit_sql(table_name, item_lst)
                item_lst.clear()
                print(item_count)

            break               

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


def submit_sql(engine, table_name, items):
''' submit dataframe content of items to sql database '''
    
    engine = connect_to_database()

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(items)
    temp_df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

    engine.dispose()


with open("C:/Path/To/Json/file.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
    s_objects = ijson.items(json_file, 'ObjectList.item')
    create_content(s_objects, 'tablename')
```

The version with a simple for-loop doesn't work either. The if-statement after the for-loop is never reached.

```
try:
    for item in objects:
        value_conversion(item)
        item_lst.append(item)
        
        if len(item_lst) == 10000:
            item_count += len(item_lst)
            submit_sql(table_name, item_lst)
            item_lst.clear()
            print(item_count)


    if len(item_lst) > 0:
        item_count += len(item_lst)
        submit_sql(table_name, item_lst)
        item_lst.clear()
        print(item_count)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: btw, you should just for-loop over `objects`, i.e, `for item in objects: ...` don't use `while True: item  = next(objects)`

Comment: The ```while True``` was introduced because the for loop with the try-except statement did in the end perform the same way and did not process the following if-statement, that is now found below the StopIteration. I simply do not get to the point where the remaining items (less then 10.000) will be processed.

Comment: then a `StopIteration` isn't being raised

Comment: I updated the original posting.

Comment: If what you say is true that means the `objects` is not empty. You claim "even though the last item of the generator was called by the next method." but apparently that isn't true -- how do you know?  There is some assumption you have here which is not true. In any case, the for-loop version should be what you are using

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24527006/1639625

Comment: I know that the final number of items in the generator is 1.384.471 because I had to figure that out in painstakingly debugging work. AFAIK, the for-loop is also using internally a StopIteration to end the loop.

Comment: I just tested a simplified version of the code, without pandas and sql, just printing each batch, and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Yes, a simplified version worked for me as well. Actually I’m both versions: while and simple for-loop. But as soon as I start with the generator from ijson trying to do the real work, the last bit is never processed. I wonder why the try-statement is never left.

Comment: @tobias_k I had a look into the posting you linked. Not that I understand much about generators, in facts it’s the first time I am working with one, but I got the impression your posting was more about how to build the generator, or am I mistaken?

Comment: That's right, but you can still use that. Use it to get the "chunks" from the `objects` iterator, then just convert those to lists, do the preprocessing on each element, and submit them to the DB.

Comment: About the loop not ending: In that case some other exception than StopIteration has to be raised and should be printed in the final except clause. Is there any? O does it just hang forever on `next`?

Comment: As far as I can tell it’s hanging for ever on next. I will try to follow your advice with the chunks.

Comment: The `chunks` function might not work then, either, almost sounds like a bug in `ijson` itself.