# Why does try except not catch StopIteration when trying to split generator into generators

Tags: python, generator

Attempt to split generator of size a*n + b into 1 generator with an items of size n each.

I believe there already exist questions to this problem with minimal modifications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527006/split-a-generator-into-chunks-without-pre-walking-it). However its perplexing that the code below returns an error despite supposedly having caught it with try except.

```
def test(vid, size):
    while True:
        try:
            part = (next(vid) for _ in range(size))
            yield part
        except StopIteration:
            break

res = test((i for i in range(100)), 30)
for i in res:
    for j in i:
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[54], line 4, in (.0)
      3 try:
----> 4     part = (next(vid) for _ in range(size))
      5     yield part

StopIteration: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[54], line 11
      9 res = test((i for i in range(100)), 30)
     10 for i in res:
---> 11     for j in i:
     12         print(i, end=" ")
     13     print()

RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Also from the print statements the remainder is also printed out instead of being discarded.

Note: Using `RuntimeError` for the except also does not catch the error

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to address:

- First note that your function yields a generator, it does not *empty* / yield from it. In short, the `try...except` must be at the place where the iteration happens, currently it is around the definition.

Lemme give you this analogy to make it (hopefully) obvious:
`foo` will **not be called inside** the `test2` function -> hence **the error cannot be caught inside.**

```
def test2():
    try:
        def foo():
            raise StopIteration
        return foo
    except StopIteration #this will not happen as foo() is not called here.
        pass

outer_foo = test2()
outer_foo() # <--- raises StopIteration
```

---

Secondly, lets go back to the generator and use your function `test`. As you said a `RuntimeError` occurs.

```
try:
   for geni in test():
       for elem in geni:
           print(elem)
except StopIteration:
    print("This is expected but does NOT HAPPEN. Why?")
except RuntimeError:
    print("Instead a RuntimeError occurs.")
```

So, why does this code not catch a `StopIteration` but produces a `RuntimeError`?

The reason is how you define your generator and how generators work in python. The generator is defined as:
`part = (next(vid) for _ in range(size))  # <--- StopIteration CANNOT be caught`

**generators in python have their own scope** the expected `StopIteration` from `next(vid)` is raised in that scope *but not handled* in the scope of the generator, it propagates *to the outside* as a `RuntimeError`.

Your generator is equivalent to.

```
for _ in range(size):
    yield next(vid)  # <--- here a StopIteration can be caught
```

This version has no "hidden" scope and behaves as expected, you just have to be aware that again the error has to be caught were the iteration over `vid` happens.

Here is a working solution that:

```
def create_batches(vid, size):
    done = False

    def batcher():
        nonlocal done
        print("--- new batch ---")
        for i in range(size):
            print("batch", i, "/", size)
            try:
                yield next(vid)
            except StopIteration:
                print("StopIteration caught, and we are done")
                done=True
                break

    while not done:
        yield batcher()
              
                
for batch in create_batches((i for i in range(10)), 3):
   for elem in batch:
       print("elem=", elem)
```

```
# --- Output --- #

--- new batch ---
batch 0 / 3
elem= 0
batch 1 / 3
elem= 1
batch 2 / 3
elem= 2
--- new batch ---
batch 0 / 3
elem= 3
batch 1 / 3
elem= 4
batch 2 / 3
elem= 5
--- new batch ---
batch 0 / 3
elem= 6
batch 1 / 3
elem= 7
batch 2 / 3
elem= 8
--- new batch ---
batch 0 / 3
elem= 9
batch 1 / 3
StopIteration caught, and we are done
```

---

Final note: You should be able to create a more compact batcher with `itertools.isclice` but for the sake of a better understanding I did not include it here.

Comment: `create_batches((i for i in range(9)), 3)` produces an empty batch at the end, I don't think that's good.