# How to split a generator into smaller generators while discarding excess

Tags: python, generator

Split generator of size a*n + b into 1 generator consisting of a generators with n items. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527006/split-a-generator-into-chunks-without-pre-walking-it), and I need similar things like

- do not walk the generator beforehand: computing the elements is expensive, and it must only be done by the consuming function, not by the chunker
- which means, of course: do not accumulate in memory (no lists)

However the difference is that I do not want the remaining few elements, if they exist. I've tried adding this block

```
size, it = tee(it) 
size = len(list(size)) 
split = (next(vid) for _ in range(size-size%length))
```

However this still requires traversing which eats up lots of memory and is not ideal.

Comment: Do you know a, n or b?

Comment: Ok, having read the linked question, I think I understand what you're looking for. But I'm not sure it's possible to skip the last incomplete chunk if you don't read at least one full chunk ahead. Would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
split = zip(*[it]*n)
```

This reads `n` values from the iterator `it` at a time, and yields them in a tuple. If there are fewer than `n` values left in the iterator, the left over ones are discarded.

It doesn't *quite* match your requirements, as it's impossible not to read ahead at least a little bit. If you don't read at least a full chunk ahead, there's no way to tell that the last chunk is incomplete before you start using the values from it.

Comment: I’m fine with reading the last unused chunk, just can’t return it. However regarding zip does it provide the save memory saving as generators or does it essentially become a list?

Comment: It reads `n` values from the input iterator, then yields them (in a tuple). Then it reads another `n` values, and so on. If it gets to the end of the input before it gets `n` values, it throws away whatever it's gathered so far.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is the [`grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from `itertools` with the `incomplete='ignore'` option.