# Getting batches from a list jpw

Tags: python

I have a function that should get parts from a list and than move in the list to get the next part or part:

```
def batch(iterable, n=1):
   l = len(iterable)
   for ndx in range(0, l, n):
      yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]
```

I've tried to use this function as followed :

```
.............................
index =0; 
values.clear()

for i in batch(my_data, 40):
   values.append(i)
   index = index +1 
   print('index', index )
```

**UPDATE**

what I'm seeing is that index value reaches 58 or 20, while I'm expecting 40

thanks in advance !

Comment: "I expect to 40 as a value but I get 58 and sometimes 20 I just get it." Sorry, I don't understand that sentence. Could you post some actual input and output?

Comment: Also, no need for `min`. `iterable[ndx:ndx + n]` should work in any case (if `iterable` supports slicing, of course)

Comment: there is probably something in `itertools` for this task already

Comment: Not in `itertools`, AFAIK, but some related question on SO, e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24527006/1639625) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/1639625)

Comment: @tobias_k I've updated the question

Comment: Why do you expect `index` to reach `40`? Do you want to split the iterable into `n` chunks, or into chunks with size `n`? Your code does the latter.

Comment: @tobias_k that is exactly why `index` has to go to 40.

Comment: well AFAIK batch function will reader 40 element from the list, so if I'm increment the index during this op, it'll reach the value of 4 0

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Why? OP is not iterating _one_ batch, but _all_ the batches. The only reason for `index` to end up at 40 would be if the original data has around 1600 entries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290397/how-to-split-an-iterable-in-constant-size-chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion as to what the code does. When called with `n=40`, it does not create 40 batches, but batches that are each 40 elements long. Thus, if you iterate the batches like you do in your loop and increase `index` in each iteration, it does not have to end up at `40`.

Take a look at this smaller example:

```
lst = list(range(20))
for b in batch(lst, 7):
    print(b)
```

In the output, you can see that there are not 7 but just 3 batches.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: should this not print then `7` then `14` and then `20` with the `print(index)`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Why? OP is doing `index = index + 1`, not `index = index + len(i)` in the loop. Thus, `index` is just the number of iterations of the loop, i.e. the number of batches.

Comment: @ Tobias thanks for the clarification, I've got it now