# How to define a batch generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have a directory with around a million images. I want to create a `batch_generator` so that I could train my CNN as I cannot hold all those images in memory at once.

So, I wrote a generator function to do so:

```
def batch_generator(image_paths, batch_size, isTraining):
    while True:
        batch_imgs = []
        batch_labels = []
        
        type_dir = 'train' if isTraining else 'test'
        
        for i in range(len(image_paths)):
            print(i)
            print(os.path.join(data_dir_base, type_dir, image_paths[i]))
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(data_dir_base, type_dir, image_paths[i]), 0)
            img  = np.divide(img, 255)
            img = img.reshape(28, 28, 1)
            batch_imgs.append(img)
            label = image_paths[i].split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
            batch_labels.append(label)
            if len(batch_imgs) == batch_size:
                yield (np.asarray(batch_imgs), np.asarray(batch_labels))
                batch_imgs = []
        if batch_imgs:
            yield batch_imgs
```

When I call this statement:

```
index = next(batch_generator(train_dataset, 10, True))
```

It is printing the same index values and paths hence, it is returning the same batch on every call of `next()`.
How do I fix this?

I used this question as a reference for the code: [how to split an iterable in constant-size chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290397/how-to-split-an-iterable-in-constant-size-chunks)

Comment: @kerwei nope, it's correctly indented, it's here to yield the last batch if it's size was < batch_size. It's a very very common "buffering" code pattern.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, I didn't notice the inner if block at first glance. Hence, deleted my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generator functions are not generators themselves but "generator factories" - each time you call `batch_generator(...)` it returns a fresh new generator, ready to start again. IOW, you want:

```
gen = batch_generator(...)
for batch in gen:       
    do_something_with(batch)
```

Also:

1/ the way you wrote your generator function will create an infinite generator - the outer while loop will repeat forever - which might or not be what you expected (thought I'd better warn you).

2/ there are two logical errors in your code: first, you don't reset the `batch_labels` list, then on the last `yield` you only yield `batch_imgs`, which is not consistant with the inner `yield`. FWIW, instead of maintaining two lists (one for the images and the other for the labels), you'd perhaps be better using one single list of `(img, label)` tuples.

And as a final side note: you don't need to use `range(len(lst))` to iterate on a list - Python's `for` loop is of the `foreach` type, it directly iterates over the iterable's items, ie:

```
for path image_paths:
    print(path)
```

works just the same, is more readable, and is a bit faster...

Comment: About the outer loop, I am going to use the generator in keras to train a CNN. So, the course I did on that used a similar implementation of the batch generator. Can you explain more about the drawbacks or benefits of infinite generator?

Comment: What you're going to use to "train a CNN" are (directly or indirectly) the results of iterating over your generator, not the generator itself. And the principle of an infinite generator is that the iteration never stops - `next(iterator)` will _always_ return something and a `for item in iterator` loop will run forever. It's impossible to tell if an infinite generator is appropriate for your own use case without seeing exactly how it's used, I just thought you might want to be warned about this since you don't really seem to fully grasp what generators are and how they work.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have a complete understanding of generators. This is my first time. But I have got it to work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
# batch generator
def get_batches(dataset, batch_size):
    X, Y = dataset
    n_samples = X.shape[0]

    # Shuffle at the start of epoch
    indices = np.arange(n_samples)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)

    for start in range(0, n_samples, batch_size):
        end = min(start + batch_size, n_samples)

        batch_idx = indices[start:end]

        yield X[batch_idx], Y[batch_idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to achieve something along this line:

```
def batch_generator(image_paths, batch_size, isTraining):
    your_code_here
```

Calling the generator - instead of what you have:

```
index = next(batch_generator(train_dataset, 10, True))
```

You can try:

```
index = iter(batch_generator(train_dataset, 10, True))
index.__next__()
```

Comment: 1/ you don't need to call `iter()` on an iterable (in this case it will actually just return it's argument unchanged), 2/ `__next__()` is a "magic method" (the implementation of a generic operator or operator-like function) and should not be called directly but thru the `next()` function.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for the pointer! Admittedly, I'm still rather new to generators. Getting into these discussions helps me to learn and improve.

Answer (score 0):

I made my own generator that supports both limit, batches or simply step 1 iteration:

```
def gen(batch = None, limit = None):
    ret = []
    for i in range(1, 11): # put your data reading here and i counter (i += 1) under for
        if batch:
            ret.append(i)
            if limit and i == limit:
                if len(ret):            
                    yield ret
                return
            if len(ret) == batch:
                yield ret
                ret = []
        else:
            if limit and i > limit:
                break
            yield i
    if batch and len(ret): # yield the rest of the list
        yield ret
            
g = gen(batch=5, limit=8) # batches with limit
#g = gen(batch=5) # batches
#g = gen(limit=5) # step 1 with limit
#g = gen() # step 1 with limit
for i in g:
    print(i)
```