# How can I consume an iterable in batches (equally sized chunks)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I am often using [`batch()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8290514/1496234) in Python. Is there some alternative in JavaScript since ES6 which has iterators and generator functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to write one for myself, which I'm sharing here for me and the others to find here easily:

```
// subsequently yield iterators of given `size`
// these have to be fully consumed
function* batches(iterable, size) {
  const it = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  while (true) {
    // this is for the case when batch ends at the end of iterable
    // (we don't want to yield empty batch)
    let {value, done} = it.next();
    if (done) return value;

    yield function*() {
      yield value;
      for (let curr = 1; curr < size; curr++) {
        ({value, done} = it.next());
        if (done) return;

        yield value;
      }
    }();
    if (done) return value;
  }
}
```

It yields generators, not `Array`s for example. You have to fully consume each batch before calling `next()` on it again.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit that makes the final value always be emitted from the outer iterator. Feel free to roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: Thanks, I like your version more .. I did not have enough 'distance' for the final cleanup;)

Answer (score 2):

Came here looking to see what other people had suggested. Here's the version I wrote in TypeScript initially before looking at this post.

```
async function* batch<T>(iterable: AsyncIterableIterator<T>, batchSize: number) {
  let items: T[] = [];
  for await (const item of iterable) {
    items.push(item);
    if (items.length >= batchSize) {
      yield items;
      items = []
    }
  }
  if (items.length !== 0) {
    yield items;
  }
}
```

This allows you to consume an iterable in batches as shown below.

```
async function doYourThing<T>(iterable: AsyncIterableIterator<T>) {
  const itemsPerBatch = 5
  const batchedIterable = batch<T>(iterable, itemsPerBatch)
  for await (const items of batchedIterable) {
    await someOperation(items)
  }
}
```

In my case, this allowed me to use bulkOps in Mongo a little more easily as demonstrated below.

```
import { MongoClient, ObjectID } from 'mongodb';
import { batch } from './batch';

const config = {
  mongoUri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test?replicaSet=rs0',
};

interface Doc {
  readonly _id: ObjectID;
  readonly test: number;
}

async function main() {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(config.mongoUri);
  const db = client.db('test');
  const coll = db.collection<Doc>('test');
  await coll.deleteMany({});
  console.log('Deleted test docs');

  const testDocs = new Array(4).fill(null).map(() => ({ test: 1 }));
  await coll.insertMany(testDocs);
  console.log('Inserted test docs');

  const cursor = coll.find().batchSize(5);
  for await (const docs of batch<Doc>(cursor as any, 5)) {
    const bulkOp = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    docs.forEach((doc) => {
      bulkOp.find({ _id: doc._id }).updateOne({ test: 2 });
    });
    console.log('Updating', docs.length, 'test docs');
    await bulkOp.execute();
  }
  console.log('Updated test docs');
}

main()
  .catch(console.error)
  .then(() => process.exit());
```

Comment: I really like your solution because it's generic. I'd propose to reduce the usage example to two or three lines though, to make it easier to see the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively clean example in Typescript:

```
function* batchIterable<T>(iter: Iterable<T>, batchSize: number): Iterable<Iterable<T>> {
    const iterator = iter[Symbol.iterator]()
    let done = false
    while (!done) {
        const batch: T[] = []
        while (batch.length < batchSize) {
            const res = iterator.next()
            if (res.done) {
                done = true
                break
            } else {
                batch.push(res.value)
            }
        }
        if (batch.length > 0) {
            yield batch
        }
    }
}
```

Works with any iterable, including arrays:

```
> Array.from(batchIterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3))
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ], [ 10 ] ]
```

And also with generators:

```
function* genNums() { 
    yield 1; 
    yield 2; 
    yield 3; 
    yield 4;
}
```

```
> Array.from(batchIterable(genNums(), 3))
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4 ] ]
```

But, not with generators that return a separate value from the yielded values:

```
function* genNums() { 
    yield 1; 
    yield 2; 
    yield 3; 
    yield 4;

    return 5;
}
```

```
> Array.from(batchIterable(genNums(), 3))
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4 ] ]  // return-ed value 5 not included
```