# How to create a partial list from iterator.combinations()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, python-itertools

I need a list of all combinations of length `t` for some computation on a GPU. I used `X=itertools.combinations(range(n),t)` to create an iterator. I need to pass all the combinations to the GPU at once, so I use `list(X)` to generate all the combinations from the iterator.

For higher values of n and t, I run out of memory. Is there a way to generate multiple smaller lists of all the combinations that can fit in the memory one at a time? For example, if I have `n=25` and `t=12`, instead of generating all `25 choose 12` combinations, can I get a list of `10,000` combinations at a time which I can process on the GPU?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to split an iterable in constant-size chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290397/how-to-split-an-iterable-in-constant-size-chunks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations, count, takewhile

n=25
t=12

chunk_size = 10000

x = combinations(range(n),t)

i = 0
while True:
    l = [*takewhile(lambda _, c=count(): next(c) < chunk_size, x)]

    # your code here, l is a list of length max. 10000 of combinations
    print(l)

    i += 1

    if len(l) < chunk_size:
        break

print('We have done {} iterations.'.format(i))
```

Prints:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 17), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 18), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 19), ...
```

And at the end:

```
We have done 520 iterations.
```